# Read pdf files in perl

Tags: perl

I have a collection of pdfs and would like to read those pdfs through a perl program. I just want to read and print those pdfs. Is there any module available in perl to do this?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/09/20/pdf-processing-with-perl.html. Probably will be of help. Thanks.

Comment: When you say read, what exactly do you want to extract?  Graphics?  Text?  Raw PDF commands?

Comment: Searched a bit and "CAM::PDF" module looks to be what you are searching for. take a look here as well http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.54/lib/CAM/PDF.pm

Comment: @Mike:i would like to extract only text from pdfs

Comment: The "to text" functionality of most perl modules is less than ideal. I usually use the pdftotext utility.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate printing, I would recommend to use the command line interface of the Acrobat reader.
If you want to parse the content, I would use CAM::PDF, but the results depend strongly on the pdf.
The command line parameters for printing are

> AcroRd32.exe  /t filename printername drivername portname

Answer (score 0):

Depending exactly what you want to do with the PDFs and their contents (that is, do you want a perl module which essentially replaces Acrobat Reader, or do you just want to extract and print the text of the documents) CPAN might provide what you want as it contains quite a few modules related to PDFs: [CPAN Search of PDF modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=PDF;s=1)